# How to get the VPC Id of an EC2 instance?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I need to identify the VpcId for the current EC2 instance using the C# AWS SDK. I have been trying to do this for a couple of hours now with no real luck.

My current approach is something like this,

```
var currentInstanceId = Amazon.EC2.Util.EC2Metadata.InstanceId; // Get Current Instance Id

AWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
var ec2Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(creds, clientRegionEndpoint);
var instances = ec2Client.DescribeInstances();

foreach (var reservation in instances.Reservations)
{
  foreach (var instance in reservation.Instances)
  {
    if (instance.InstanceId.Equals(currentInstanceId)) // Compare Instance Id with all available instances 
      return instance.VpcId;
  }
}
```

I feel like there should be an easier way to do this. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

---

**Update:**

With @jbird's help I was able to achieve this using,

```
Amazon.EC2.Util.EC2Metadata.NetworkInterfaces.First().VpcId
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under [Amazon.EC2.Util.EC2Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2UtilEC2Metadata.html) look under `NetworkInterfaces`. Each network interface has a `VpcId`.

This gets the VPC ID from the EC2 instance's metadata at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/${mac}/vpc-id`. ([Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html))

Comment: Thanks @jbird for the info, I will check this out tomorrow and accept if it works.

Comment: To clarify just a bit, it's actually `/latest/meta-data/network/macs/${mac}/vpc-id`, where `${mac}` is the response you get from from  `/latest/meta-data/mac`.  Requires two requests, looking up the mac and then the vpc of the mac.

Comment: Finally was able to check this. This is working as expected. Thanks jbird and Michael.

Comment: It looks weird, but this does work: curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs)vpc-id

Comment: True, that curl does work, but it's still two requests. And if you add the token header required by IMDSv2, it gets even more unwieldy. I'd probably choose to split it.